# How to retrieve two IMAP4.select()

Tags: python, imap

I'd like to retrieve two folders using the select method. I'd like to get the "Inbox" as well as the "Sent".

Is there a way to do this? Currently, the only way I know of, I can only get one folder at a time using:

```
IMAP4.select('INBOX')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting an IMAP folder does not retrieve any messages, it just selects that folder. If you to get a message (or attributes of it like flags or the internal date), you need to use FETCH.

If you want to get all messages in two folders, simply loop through each of them in turn.